# access extjs elements outside onReady

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, extjs

I have created a Layout using ExtJs. It consists of a left menu and a main tabbed panel (the main components I am using are: Ext.tree.Panel and Ext.tab.Panel inside a Ext.Viewport)

Once a menu element is clicked it is loaded (via Ajax POST) in a tab. This is made using jQuery.

Once a certain button (inside a tab) is clicked, I must load some more content via Ajax. My question is how to access Ext elements in the scope of the tabs (which are created using a PHP-based MVC).

By example, how could I do something like this?:

```
var tab = mainPanel.getActiveTab();
alert('Current tab: ' + tab.title);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have configured your Ext.tab.Panel with an id (e.g. id: tabPanel):

```
{
region: 'center',
id: 'tabPanel',
xtype: 'tabpanel',
plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabReorderer')             
}
```

You can use `tab = Ext.getCmp('tabPanel').getActiveTab()` outside of Ext.onReady

Ext.onReady doesn't apply any scope it just delays loading the js it contains until the ExtJS library finishes loading.

**EDIT:** And then of course you could do `tab.title` - I just noticed that `.title` is not listed as a property in the Ext.tab.Tab API doc but I tested it and it is the correct usage.